# Generating list of dates

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say I have a start date in Cell A1 and an end date in Cell A2. How would I go about generating a list of dates that start at A1 and then skips 2 weeks (not 14 days, but 2 actual weeks). However, these weeks must fall exactly on the 15th and 1st of each month. Here is an example:

```
Cell A1 -> January 1, 2013
Cell A2 -> April 30, 2013
```

The macro would generate the following dates:

```
January 1, 2013
January 15, 2013
February 1, 2013
February 15, 2013
March 1, 2013
March 15, 2013
April 1, 2013
April 15, 2013
```

Many thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. Write 1st and 15th of each month until the End date ?

Comment: And do you want the dates in cells, or just in a VBA array?

Comment: Cells would be preferable

Comment: Your example output does not match your description. Those are not actual weeks. They are arbitrary uneven time slices, they are the 1st and the 15th, they are not 2 weeks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Sub GenerateDates()

Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date

FirstDate = Range("A1").Value
LastDate = Range("a2").Value

NextDate = FirstDate
Range("B1").Select

Do Until NextDate >= LastDate

    ActiveCell.Value = NextDate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    If Day(NextDate) = 1 Then
        NextDate = DateAdd("d", NextDate, 14)
    Else
        NextDate = DateAdd("d", NextDate, 20)
        NextDate = DateSerial(Year(NextDate), Month(NextDate), 1)
    End If

Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: The macro adds on 14 days each time if it's the first of the month, or adds on 20 days (an arbitrary amount) otherwise, to ensure we're in the following month, then takes the first day for this month.

Comment: Since Activate and Select are generally discouraged in VBA unless absolutely necessary, I'd encourage you to code it without those two actions.

Comment: For the amount of time this macro will take to run, it won't make any difference.  However, you could set the value of Cells(RowNumber,ColNumber) instead, incrementing RowNumber on each pass through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

A small amount of manual work but it can be done as a cell formula. If **b1** `=a1` then **b2** is:

```
=if(day(b1)=1, date(year(b1),month(b1),15), date(year(b1),month(b1)+1,1))
```

Now the manual work, drag this cell formula down keeping the relative cell references until the desired date is reached. Then paste values if necessary.